# Factorial function in Python with print function

Tags: python, factorial

```
def factorial(n):
   """Function to return the factorial
   of a number using recursion"""
   if n == 1:
       return n
   else:
       return n*factorial(n-1)

def main():
    for i in range(1,10):
        f = factorial(i)
        print(f'{i}! = {f}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For the result I keep getting an error message that says "Invalid Syntax" where the print statement is.

I am creating a factorial function where I want the output to look like this:

```
 1!=1
 2!=2
 3!=6
 4!=24
 5!=120
 6!=720
 7!=5040
 8!=40320
 9!=362880
```

I have checking my code over and over to see of I have made any errors but I didn't detect any.

Comment: Are you using Python 3.7 or later (which are the only versions that support f-strings)? If not, use `'{}! = {}'.format(n, f)` instead.

Comment: You are saying f=factorial(n), but n is not defined anywhere..

Comment: @BlueRineS That's probably a typo; it wouldn't produce a syntax error.

Comment: @maria please do not delete your code snippet and result/error description - they are part of the question.

Comment: @maria cf chepner's first comment, which is very probably your issue.

Comment: changed from 'n' to 'i' in main finction. ran on python 3.7. no errors.... @maria please attach exact error

Comment: I am using Python 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def factorial(n):
"""Function to return the factorial of a number using recursion"""
if n == 1:
    return n
else:
    return n*factorial(n-1)

def main():
    print("NOTE: Parameter n has to be greater or equal to 1")
    n = int(input("Parameter 1: "))
    m = int(input("Parameter 2: "))
    print()
    for i in range(n,m):
        f = factorial(i)
        #print(f'{i}! = {f})
        print("{}! = {}".format(i, f))

 if __name__ == "__main__":
       main()
```

Comment: NOTE: Parameter n has to be greater or equal to 1
Parameter 1: 3
Parameter 2: 12

3! = 6
4! = 24
5! = 120
6! = 720
7! = 5040
8! = 40320
9! = 362880
10! = 3628800
11! = 39916800

Comment: This is the output

Comment: It is, but why did you add user input?

Comment: Sorry I did that for my own personal preference. I forgot to take it out before posting it on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The print statement

```
print(f'{n}! = {f}')
```

may arise a SyntaxError if you are using Python version lower than 3.6 - read [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

The f-string syntax is introduced in that version.

If you're using a lower version you can try using the `format` method - read [here](https://pyformat.info/) - as so:

```
print("{}! = {}".format(n, f))
```